# mysql update column like increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update `total_playtime`(timestamp) with value with `playtime`(timestamp) and another value in the following manner.

```
total_playtime = total_playtime + playtime
```

I have used the following code,

```
UPDATE `user_data` SET `total_playtime`=total_playtime+playtime WHERE id=1
```

However this code **only works** when,

```
>>if second + second, works only when the result is no more than 1 minute. 
for example 
00:00:05 + 00:00:10 = 00:00:15 //WORKS
00:00:30 + 00:00:50 = 00:00:00 //DIDNT WORK , it should be 00:01:20

>>if minute + minute, works only when the result is no more than 1 hour
for example 
00:05:00 + 00:10:00 = 00:15:00 //WORKS
00:30:00 + 00:50:00 = 00:00:00 //DIDNT WORK , it should be 01:20:00
```

That is, if the result is a convert from second to minute, or minute to hour, the result is 00:00:00.

I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and expected result ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra it's already there, "it should be 00:01:20" and "it should be 01:20:00"

Comment: Can you verify the type of the two fields are Timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will  work:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('00:00:50', '00:00:15');
```

output:

```
00:01:05
```

input:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('00:50:00', '00:30:00');
```

output:

```
01:20:00
```

for two timestamps you need to do this :

```
SELECT ADDTIME(TIME('2008-05-15 13:20:32'),Time('0001-01-01 1:39:27'))
```

Comment: This will not work for the timestamp datatype

Comment: @JoakimDanielson for your kind information this also works for timestamp datatype you can check i have already done all inputs outputs

Comment: Hmm, not when I tested your code

Comment: @JoakimDanielson now its ok? see lasts lines

Answer (score 0):

Your `total_playtime` and `playtime` should NOT be `timestamp` type.

You should use `decimal` or `int` to record the seconds.

`timestamp` means a time point. What you need is the duration. `decimal` or `int` works, then you can format the duration (by your program) to show the '00:02:30' to users.

And if you are using MySQL,  `timestamp` won't work at all.

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

ps: some databases provide `time` type which can be used to store your playtime, and you can use `addtime()` or `total_time = time + interval xxx` to calculate the total time.

Comment: There is also a `time` data type in mysql, which was specifically designed to record periods, as opposed to points in time.

Comment: Thanks, updated. ps: the question doesn't mention what database it is. `decimal` or `int` is general solution.

Comment: This feels more like a comment/design review than an answer to the question. The tag says MySql

Comment: That's impossible. You can not store '00:00:10' to mysql's timestamp. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I know that, I just mentioned the dbms the question was tagged with. Maybe ask the OP instead.